# java swing cardLayout.show() does nothing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, cardlayout

So I'm new in Java programming and have a problem. When I try to switch to a specific panel using .show(), nothing happens, but when I use .next(), it works. I need to switch to a panel called game1 using a button on my MainPanel panel. This is what I have:

```
        private void game1buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout)(MainPanel.getLayout());
            cardLayout.show(MainPanel, ""+game1);
        }
```

Here is my full code: 
*Note: I'm using NetBeans to save time.

```
    package card;

    import java.awt.CardLayout;
    public class CardTester extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        /**
         * Creates new form CardTester
         */
        public CardTester() {
            initComponents();
        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
         * regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            MainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            MainMenu = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            game1button = new javax.swing.JButton();
            game2button = new javax.swing.JButton();
            game3button = new javax.swing.JButton();
            game1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            game2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            game2menubutton = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
            game3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
            jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
            jRadioButton3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            MainPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

            jLabel1.setText("Main Menu");

            game1button.setText("Game 1");
            game1button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    game1buttonActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            game2button.setText("Game 2");
            game2button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    game2buttonActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            game3button.setText("Game 3");

            javax.swing.GroupLayout MainMenuLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(MainMenu);
            MainMenu.setLayout(MainMenuLayout);
            MainMenuLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                MainMenuLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(MainMenuLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(MainMenuLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(MainMenuLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(138, 138, 138)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGroup(MainMenuLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                            .addGroup(MainMenuLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(game3button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 287, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(game2button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(game1button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            MainMenuLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                MainMenuLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(MainMenuLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 18, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(game1button)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(game2button)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(game3button)
                    .addContainerGap())
            );

            MainPanel.add(MainMenu, "card2");

            jLabel2.setText("Game 1");

            jButton1.setText("menu");

            jTextField1.setText("This is game number 1.");
            jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            javax.swing.GroupLayout game1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(game1);
            game1.setLayout(game1Layout);
            game1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                game1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(game1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(61, 61, 61)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, game1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 238, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(42, 42, 42))
            );
            game1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                game1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(game1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(game1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 70, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18))
            );

            MainPanel.add(game1, "card3");

            jLabel3.setText("Game 2");

            game2menubutton.setText("menu");

            jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
                String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
                public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
                public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
            });
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

            javax.swing.GroupLayout game2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(game2);
            game2.setLayout(game2Layout);
            game2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                game2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(game2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(game2menubutton)
                    .addGap(82, 82, 82)
                    .addGroup(game2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addContainerGap(153, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            game2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                game2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(game2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(game2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(game2menubutton)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            );

            MainPanel.add(game2, "card4");

            jLabel4.setText("Game 3");

            jButton2.setText("menu");

            jRadioButton1.setText("jRadioButton1");

            jRadioButton2.setText("jRadioButton2");

            jRadioButton3.setText("jRadioButton3");

            javax.swing.GroupLayout game3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(game3);
            game3.setLayout(game3Layout);
            game3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                game3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(game3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(game3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(game3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4))
                        .addGroup(game3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(102, 102, 102)
                            .addGroup(game3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton3))))
                    .addContainerGap(135, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            game3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                game3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(game3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(game3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(jButton2))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton3)
                    .addGap(0, 12, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            MainPanel.add(game3, "card5");

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(MainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(MainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void game2buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                           

        private void game1buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout)(MainPanel.getLayout());
            cardLayout.show(MainPanel, ""+game1);
        }                                           

        private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                           

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CardTester.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CardTester.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CardTester.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CardTester.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new CardTester().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JPanel MainMenu;
        private javax.swing.JPanel MainPanel;
        private javax.swing.JPanel game1;
        private javax.swing.JButton game1button;
        private javax.swing.JPanel game2;
        private javax.swing.JButton game2button;
        private javax.swing.JButton game2menubutton;
        private javax.swing.JPanel game3;
        private javax.swing.JButton game3button;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JList jList1;
        private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
        private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
        private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton3;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

Edit: I solved this by adding the name 'game1' to the panel 'game1'. This associates 'game1' with the panel. My mistake was that in this:

```
     cardLayout.show(MainPanel, "game1");
```

the 'game1' was the panel name and not the card name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the child panel to his parent, you do this:

```
MainPanel.add(game1, "card3");
```

"card3" is the name you must use to refer to that child panel, so then you must use:

```
cardLayout.show(MainPanel, "card3");
```

Comment: By 'card', do you mean a panel on the 'MainPanel'?

Comment: I refer to children panels

Comment: Thank you, I would have voted up but I need a higher reputation. My problem was that I was referring to the panel name rather than the card name.